# Worker service picking up appsettings.Prodcution.json in AWS ECS QA environment

Tags: configuration, teamcity, .net-6.0, amazon-ecs

We have a .NET 6 worker service. It has appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.QA.json and appsettings.Production.json files for different environments.

When run locally, `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variables in `launchSettings.json` file allow it to pick the matching appsettings file. For instance, if `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is set to QA, appsettings.QA.json file is used.

But when deploying this service to AWS ECS QA, it picks up appsettings.Production.json. What could be the reason?

It may be a TeamCity pipeline/Docker issue, but not sure where to look.

Comment: You are you setting setting `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` as environment variables on the docker container? If not, have you tried doing that?